# Why is the cache busting rule declared in web.config being ignored?

Tags: asp.net, html, web-config, html5boilerplate

I'm trying to use the rewrite rule from the [HTML 5 Boilerplate project](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/wiki/web.config) to make circumventing browser cache (aka cache busting):

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Cachebusting">
            <match url="^(.+)\.\d+(\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://chewsy.com{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

If i try to access my css with `/css/all.123456.css`, it fails to find the file with the error reporting that it's looking for `/css/all.123456.css` (no rewrite).  I've tried commenting out the `"Remove WWW"` rule to see if that was a conflict, but same behavior.

Any ideas why this rule isn't being applied and rewriting the URLs?

**Update:** I'm using these settings for my web server in VS2010:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<match url="^(.+)\.\d+\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.{R:2}" />
```

I pressume you want to get `/css/all.css`, if not, post the desired result...

**EDIT:** VS internal development server (Cassini) doesn't support IIS URL Rewriting Module, you would have to use IIS (Express) for that, or some third party component (http://urlrewriter.net/)...

Comment: That didn't change anything. Same result, which means that `/css/all.123456.css` didn't resolve to `/css/all.css`.

Comment: @TMC - well what is it resolving **to**?

Comment: I'm getting a 404. It looks like it's not being reewritten at all.

Comment: @TMC you should see the non existant path in the query string of your error page (or in its text, don't know how you handled it), what is it - and does `/css/all.css` still exist (maybe you are getting it from the cache)

Comment: It's throwing a 404. The error page says the `The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. ` and the "Requested URL" is listed as `/css/all.2012062401.css`.  `/css/all.css` *does* exist.

Comment: @TMC - well even your original code should have worked, I just optimized it a little, so maybe your IIS Url Rewrite Module is not working? you are probably hating me already by now, but you are on IIS (not development server), and have installed the module?

Comment: I actually am on development server, using localhost. Aren't web.config rewrite rules applied when working locally? URL rewrite module is installed.

Comment: @TMC - I meant the VS internal development server (Cassini), if you are for sure on IIS then I am stumped, could be anything really at this point...

Comment: I added screenshot of my web server config in VS. I didn't realize that could make a difference.

Comment: Aha! That was theproblem. Once I switched to IIS Express, the url rewrite worked! If you update your answer to add in this info, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @TMC - if you would be so kind to accept **and** upvote the answer, so I would cross that magic 1000 reputation number, and finally see what's the air like on the other side...